# Pages library missing?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

We've enabled the publishing feature in our collection, but the 'Pages' library is completely missing. The site pages library is  there, but not pages, and I can't see anything of note in the ULS logs. How can I diagnose this better to work out what is happening?

Comment: "The site pages library is there, but not site pages" please clarify

Comment: @RobertLindgren Done! Whoops! Sorry about that